# Change the video and start it at the specific point

Tags: actionscript-3, video-streaming, flv, mp4, seek

Good afternoon staff.
I'm having a problem and I do not think the solution. I'm new using Flash.
I have a video player and now we are implementing an HD button, the player always starts the video and 360P format and stream begins, if the user click on the HD I need to save the time of the video when it was clicked and then call another file. mp4 720P and start it at the same point that was recorded.
I've tried various ways using CONNECTION.STREAM.seek(TIME); and always starts at (0), I feel that because of not being in Buffering he does not understand.
Can anyone help me solve this?

If you want I can post the code in my class connection.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This basicaly has not so much to do with Flash or AS3.
This is the server side problem.

If you are streaming file directly from the server. like:

```
resource = 'http://video.mysite.com/trainings/video1.flv';
```

Then you will be able to seek it as much as it has loaded. If the video is 20min length. and it has loaded only 50%, you will be able to seek only to the 10th min.

If you want to achive what you want. You need to take a look at HTTP PreudoStreaming or any other RTMP streaming server solitions like RED5 / Wowza / Flash Media Server.

pseudo streaming:
https://github.com/ramonfritsch/php-f4v-streming